# How can I test sorting algorithms for stability in C?

Tags: c, sorting

I have three sorting algorithms: bubble, insertion, selection.
I need to experimentally test them for stability. I understand that I need to somehow compare the same numbers before sorting and after, but I don't know how to do it in C.
I need some advice on how this can be implemented.

Comment: Duplicate the array and sort it with a proven function such as the library `qsort` and compare the sorted arrays with `memcmp`.

Comment: @WeatherVane `qsort` isn't guaranteed to be stable so that won't help.

Comment: @zwol come to think of it, I have noticed that thanks.

Comment: Generally, when comparing if you do: `if (arr[left] <= arr[right])` the sort will be stable. If you did: `if (arr[left] < arr[right])` it will be unstable. To verify your sort (e.g.) use: `typedef struct { int value; int index; } data_t;` Fill them with your values and the corresponding [original] index. Sort the `data_t` array(s). You can check for insort: `if (arr[i].data > arr[i+1].data) out_of_sort(); if (arr[i].data == arr[i+1].data) if (arr[i].index > arr[i+1].index) sort_unstable();`

Comment: Are you doing it probabilisticly? you probably can't *prove* that it's stable, just a high degree of certainty. You have to have equal key elements to test the stability, and you know that bubble and insertion are stable.

Comment: You cannot check for stability if you sort numbers using their natural ordering, because a stable sort and an unstable sort will produce identical results. You need to sort things that are NOT numbers, or sort numbers NOT using their natural ordering.

Answer (score 2):

As chqrlie has rightly pointed out, the following approach does NOT prove absence of stability mistakes for all inputs. It is however something of a smoke-test, which actually has a chance to detect implementation mistakes. This is at least a small step ahead to trying to test based on sequences of numbers, which do NOT allow detecting ANY stability mistake.

In order to test stability you therefore need to do sorting on elements which have the same sorting key AND can still be told apart outside of the sorting.
One way would be to sort elements with two keys. One is non-unique, i.e. there are pairs of elements with the same first key. The other, second key is unique, i.e. no two elements have the same second key.

Then create several pairs of elements with same first key and different second key.
Then sort.
Then verify that the relative position of elements with same first key have not changed, use the non-identical second key to do so.
Then sort again and verify that the elements with same first key have again not changed (relative) location. This is for paranoia, the algorithm (strictly speaking the tested implementation) might be stable from an unsorted list, but unstable on a sorted one.

Then restart with unsorted list/array, similar to before, but with reversed relative location of elements with identical first key.
Then sort and verify unchanged relative location AND reverse relative location compared to first sorting.
Then sort again and verify for paranoia.

As mentioned this will not detect ALL stability mistakes, but at least there are two improvements over a simple "do and verify" test here.

- test unsorted and sorted (described as paranoia), this will detect all toggle-based stability mistakes, i.e. any mechanisms to always change the relative order of same-keyed pairs
- test both "directions" of same keyed pairs, this at leat ensures detection of all stability mistakes which are caused by some kind of "preferred order", by making sure that the non-preferred order is among the test inputs and would get sorted into the preferred order

Comment: With this approach, you may prove that a given sorting algorithm is unstable if you are lucky, but if not, you cannot prove that the implementation is stable for all inputs.

Comment: True, but this is the case for next to all testing. Testing never proves absence of mistakes, for that exhaustive analysis is needed. Reasonably useful testing can however be able to detect mistakes not found by review - and then yes, luck is needed.

Comment: @chqrlie I incorporated your feedback in the shape of a clarification/disclaimer, which stresses the scope of testability here, I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If one is going to test it probabilistically, one needs to have, at minimum, key and a monotonic value to test if they are the same order before and after. There are several ways that one can do this. I would think that one of the simpler, more effective, ways is to sort them by oddness: the key is `{ even, odd }` and the value is the integer. Having only two values increases the chance that the non-stable sort algorithms put it in the wrong spot *per* item. Here, the `qsort` function is tested.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

static int cmp(const int *const a, const int *const b)
    { return (*a & 1) - (*b & 1); }

static int void_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) { return cmp(a, b); }

int main(void) {
    unsigned a[10], counter = 0;
    size_t i;
    const size_t a_size = sizeof a / sizeof *a;
    const unsigned seed = (unsigned)clock();

    /* http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html */
    printf("Seed %u.\n", seed), srand(seed);
    for(i = 0; i < a_size; i++)
        a[i] = (counter += 1 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (2 - 1 + 1) + 1));
    qsort(a, a_size, sizeof *a, &void_cmp);

    for(i = 0; i < a_size; i++) printf("%s%u", i ? ", " : "", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

    /* Even numbers. */
    for(counter = 0, i = 0; i < a_size && !(a[i] & 1) && counter < a[i];
        counter = a[i], i++);
    if(i == a_size) goto pass;
    if(!(a[i] & 1)) goto fail; /* Not stable by `counter >= a[i]`. */

    /* Odd numbers. */
    for(counter = 0; i < a_size && counter < a[i]; counter = a[i], i++);
    if(i == a_size) goto pass;

fail:
    printf("Not stable.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

pass:
    printf("Possibly stable.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that this doesn't prove that an algorithm is stable, but after sorting a large number of elements, the chance that it gets it right by chance is exponentially small.

Comment: The reason I set it to `a[10]` is it kept saying the sort was stable much under that; this was bugging me. The `C` standard doesn't say which sort it performs, but usually, `qsort` is (at least very similar) to [Bentley, McIlroy, 1993, Engineering](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.8162&rep=rep1&type=pdf). This uses insertion sort for all elements under a certain limit, and that is stable, so that's why one has to have a certain number of elements to manifest instability.